# Not able to ping Raspberry via Mac

Tags: raspbmc, macos

I have just installed successfully (it seems...) Raspbmc on the Raspberry PI but when I try to ping it from the Macbook via Terminal the request times out because "host is down".

Both the Macbook and the Raspberry PI are connected to the same wireless network.

It seems Raspberry PI is invisible to my Macbook for some reason even though logging into my router I can see that the Raspberry is connected to the wireless network and has been assigned an IP address. 
When I try to scan the wireless network from my Mac either via Terminal or other apps no devices are found (even my iPad or iPhone).

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the IP addresses of your respective devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance of ping command failure when ICMP is disabled in either of your devices.

You can also check the firewall and Upnp configurations of both raspberry Pi and Mac.